The number of series with 12 elements with conditions:
this is the question:

what is the number of series $a_1,a_2,...a_{12}$ so that:
(1):$$a_k\in\{-1,1\}$$
(2):$$\sum_{i=1}^{12}a_i=0$$
(3):$$\forall \,1 \leq k \leq 12\quad \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i\geq 0$$
(4):$$\exists \,1 \leq m \leq 11 \quad \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i=0$$

here's what I tried:
from condition (2), we know that at the end there will be an equal number of 1's and -1's, meaning 6 and 6.
from condition (3) we know that at each given "moment", there are at the very least as many 1's
and -1's.
from condition (4) there exists some point where there are as many 1's as -1's.
So I tried to convert the problem to a problem with lattice paths: let the 1's be moves to the right and -1's be moves up. what is the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(6,6)$ that don't cross the line $y=x$, and also touch the line at some point $(n,n)$ (because of the 4th condition).
So I thought the solution to the lattice paths version of the answer is the number of paths from (0,0) to (n,n) without crossing y=x, times the number of paths from (n,n) to (6,6) without crossing y=x. Thus the answer should be $C_n \cdot C_{6-n}$ for some $n$ and for all $n$, the answer is $$\sum_{n=1}^5 C_n \cdot C_{6-n}=1*42+2*14+5*5+14*2+42*1=165$$
as it turns out, that is not the correct answer. So what did I do wrong and what is the correct answer?

Easier to compute the number of Dyck paths that never re-touch $0$, then subtract.

You are overcounting. The path which touches $x=y$ at both $(1, 1)$ and $(2, 2)$ is being counted by you in both $C_1 \cdot C_5$ and $C_2 \cdot C_4$. It would be easier to subtract the negative as @lulu said, but If you do want to add for some reason, you would have to apply inclusion exclusion over all subsets of ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5}$
